# Is it possible for runtime .NET Core 3.1 and 6.0 to coexist on an Ubuntu system

Tags: software-installation, .net

Is it possible for runtime .NET Core 3.1 and 6.0 to coexist on an Ubuntu system (for example, Ubuntu 22.04)?

Let me explain, I have a computer where I need both runtimes, but either I install one or the other. I can't seem to get them to work together. The installation for version 3.1 is done like this:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb  
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb  
apt update  
apt install apt-transport-https dotnet-runtime-3.1 -y
```

And for version 6.0, I use the following steps:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
```

However, when I run `dotnet --list-runtimes`, I only see version 3.1. If I only perform the installation of 6.0, only that one is displayed. But never both.

Comment: My usual remark: don't just download over HTTP a package and then install it with dpkg -i: it can't be validated cryptographically. Instead, add back the previous version's repository (possibly adjust preferences: man apt_preferences), so it can be downloaded using apt and be verified to not have been tampered with. I'm talking here about package libssl1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make them coexist with the following lines:

```
apt remove --purge dotnet* aspnet* netstandard* -y
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/39c3ef4c-73c7-4248-8c54-0865d5feb8b2/3420b1ff6b0f36e63044d6f7a794b579/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.32-linux-x64.tar.gz
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/fea239ad-fd47-4764-aa71-6a147a82f632/20ee58b0bf08ae9f6e76e37ba3765c57/dotnet-runtime-3.1.32-linux-x64.tar.gz
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/56d44b17-03c2-4d9e-bdbc-a598ca34fc01/8fcc1e19dfd3c86b09beb68460db6e85/aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.21-linux-x64.tar.gz
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/25fc0412-b2ff-4868-9920-c087b8a75c55/a95292a725fc37c909c4432c74ecdb43/dotnet-runtime-6.0.21-linux-x64.tar.gz
mkdir /opt/dotnet 
tar zxf aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.21-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/
tar zxf aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.32-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/
tar zxf dotnet-runtime-3.1.32-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/
tar zxf dotnet-runtime-6.0.21-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/
mkdir /usr/share/dotnet
ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
dotnet --list-runtimes
```